# Is there any like Rstudio's help section in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, ide, rstudio, jupyter

I'm learning Python and I use Jupyter. I really miss help section of RStudio. It's possible that in python exists something similar with the syntaxis of functions? If it doesn't exist, how I can read the documentation in one place, or I need to google it for all functions?

Thanks!!

Comment: `help(object)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using JupyterLab interface for notebooks, you can use the inspector as you type, see [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4031#issuecomment-368941934). It seems it is now being referred to as 'contextual help'. If you use the `launch binder` badge from [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) to start a session, you'll see it listed as 'Contextual Help' in the launcher under 'Other'. The launcher can be accessed via `File` > `New Launcher`. See a demo of it in action [here](https://twitter.com/chowthedog/status/1169661354283798529).